# How to click on a value in the table

Tags: javascript

I want top click a value in the dynamic table where my values location can be anywhere depends on the login user permission. so I can't go with the  index.
I need to search that value by text and need to click on it.

When I am doing it through IDE, it's doing type function will is not resolving my problem, when I am converting type methoc into click then it's going with .

Plz help me on this.

Comment: Your English is confusing, try reexplaining your problem

Comment: post some code you worked with, which will let us understand your problem..

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, you have possibility to use javascript library like JQuery, for instance, and get your table's cell [using its selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). I think it will be the simple way.